# Local variable position on stack not changing

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I am currently reading a book security vulnerabilities and have come to the section on stack-based buffer overflows. It gives an example similar to the one that follows.

```
//overFlowTest.c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main(int argv, char* argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    char buffer[4];
    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
    if(i)
    {
        printf("overwrote i\n");
    }
}
```

When I compile and run the program with an input argument that is longer than the available space allocated for that variable "AAAAA", I get the following as expected (because I overwrote the i variable since it has a numerically larger address (lower in the stack) on the stack than "buffer").

```
# gcc overFlowTest.c
# ./a.out AAAAA
overwrote buffer
#
```

But then when I change the order of how the local variables are created, I would think they would get pushed to the stack in the opposite order and the buffer overflow would not work.

```
//overFlowTest.c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main(int argv, char* argv[])
{
    char buffer[4];
    int i = 0;
    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
    if(i)
    {
        printf("overwrote i\n");
    }
}
```

But this does not seem to be the case, as I get the same result.

```
# gcc overFlowTest.c
# ./a.out AAAAA
overwrote buffer
#
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: I don't think compiler allocate stack based on the order of variables and also if optimization is enabled, the compiler probably throws the variable "i" away

Comment: also note that "AAAAA" is actually 6 character, you should count for '\0' at the end

Comment: It's undefined behaviour. If you want to know what happens step through the assembly code with a debugger.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I have done a great deal of that but didn't think it would be helpful to have a bunch of assembly in this post.  In both situations, the assembly instructions and locations of the local variables on the stack are the same relative to one another, which is puzzling to me.  I am wondering if it is something that GCC is doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I found some interesting information while exploring this problem.

One, this problem is not reproduced with clang.  When I compile the second program, I don't see the print statement as shown here:

```
$ clang so.c -o so.out
so.c:4:1: warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int' [-Wmain-return-type]
void main(int arg, char* argv[])
^
so.c:4:1: note: change return type to 'int'
void main(int arg, char* argv[])
^~~~
int
1 warning generated.

$ clang so2.c -o so2.out
so2.c:4:1: warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int' [-Wmain-return-type]
void main(int arg, char* argv[])
^
so2.c:4:1: note: change return type to 'int'
void main(int arg, char* argv[])
^~~~
int
1 warning generated.

$ ./so.out AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
overwrote i

$ ./so2.out AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

$
```

However, if we do the same with gcc, we see that they both fail.

```
$ gcc so.c -o so.exe

$ gcc so2.c -o so2.exe

$ ./so.exe AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
overwrote i

$ ./so2.exe AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
overwrote i

$
```

Looking a bit further, let's look at the assembly for these

```
$ gcc so.c -S -masm=intel

$ gcc so2.c -S -masm=intel

$ diff so.s so2.s
1c1
<       .file   "so.c"
---
>       .file   "so2.c"

$
```

As you can see, the only difference here is the filename (I also tested with all optimizations off, with the same result).

Now, let's try with clang.

```
$ clang -S -mllvm --x86-asm-syntax=intel so.c
so.c:4:1: warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int' [-Wmain-return-type]
void main(int arg, char* argv[])
^
so.c:4:1: note: change return type to 'int'
void main(int arg, char* argv[])
^~~~
int
1 warning generated.

$ clang -S -mllvm --x86-asm-syntax=intel so2.c
so2.c:4:1: warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int' [-Wmain-return-type]
void main(int arg, char* argv[])
^
so2.c:4:1: note: change return type to 'int'
void main(int arg, char* argv[])
^~~~
int
1 warning generated.

$ diff so.s so2.s
26c26
<       lea     rax, qword ptr [rbp - 24]
---
>       lea     rax, qword ptr [rbp - 20]
29c29
<       mov     dword ptr [rbp - 20], 0
---
>       mov     dword ptr [rbp - 24], 0
34c34
<       cmp     dword ptr [rbp - 20], 0
---
>       cmp     dword ptr [rbp - 24], 0

$
```

It looks like clang compiles the two files to different versions; this prevents i from being overwritten.

In conclusion, the reason why these two files produce different output is because the code produces undefined behaviour - the compiler is not bound by any standards and can produce whatever is easiest.

Comment: Interesting! I was thinking it had something to do with GCC. I was able to reproduce the same results as the ones that you posted above.  Thank you for your thorough investigation into this.